# Design-time error in WPF valueconverter

Tags: .net, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have a converter class:

```
Imports System.Windows.Markup

Public Class ValueToColorConverter
    Inherits MarkupExtension
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim v As Double = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value)
        If v > 0 Then
            Return New SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(70, 120, 50))
        Else
            Return Brushes.White
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New System.NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ProvideValue(ByVal serviceProvider As System.IServiceProvider) As Object
        Return Me
    End Function
End Class
```

And I am using it in XAML:

```
<local:ValueToColorConverter x:Key="ValueToColorConverter" />
```

Visual Studio is at design time showing in error list

```
No constructor for type 'ValueToColorConverter' has 0 parameters
```

Project builds ok and converter works well at runtime.
**Why is the error shown at design time and how to remove it?**

Comment: Did you try restarting visual studio? I suspect you had parameters earlier and removed later.

Comment: Clean & Rebuild may also work. I would try both suggestions.

Comment: Yes, restart+clean&build seemed to work. This error appears once in a while but I suppose it is not something to worry about.

Comment: Do you really need to inherit MarkupExtension? You can use Converters with just the Interface implementation

Comment: I can get rid of the MarkupExternsion here, if that is the issue.